# Different type inference results with javac and ecj

Tags: java, type-inference

I have a problem with Java's type-inference. I am using javac 1.8.0_121, and the following code does compile with Eclipse ECJ, but not with javac

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Playbook {

    static class A {
    }

    static class B {
    }

    static class P<T> {
    }

    static class V<T> {  
        static <T, U> V<U> m(P<T> src, Function<? super T, ? extends U> f, Function<? super U, ? extends T> g) {
            return null;
        }

        void b(final P<T> other) {

        }
    }

    public void bindTimeString1(P<A> p1, P<B> p2) {
        V.m(p2, s -> new A(), t -> new B()).b(p1);
    }    
}
```

Compiling this with javac results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Playbook.java:[31,47] incompatible types: main.java.Playbook.P<main.java.Playbook.A> cannot be converted to main.java.Playbook.P<java.lang.Object>
```

Without the second parameter `g` of `m` the code compiles without problems:

import java.util.function.Function;

```
public class Playbook {

    static class A {
    }

    static class B {
    }

    static class P<T> {
    }

    static class V<T> {
        static <T, U> V<U> m(P<T> src, Function<? super T, ? extends U> f) {
            return null;
        }

        void b(P<T> other) {

        }
    }

    public void bindTimeString2(P<A> p1, P<B> p2) {
        V.m(p2, s -> new A()).b(p1);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this fails in the first place. From the code, the compiler can infer that:

- f returns something that extends U.
- g accepts something that is a base-class of U.
- From g's body nothing more can be inferred about U.
- From f`s body, it knows that it returns an A, so A <: U must be true.
- Var.b does not place any more constraints on U, so U could be any type that satisfies A <: U. In this case, this leaves us with A or Object as potential candidates for U.

It seems that the compiler chooses Object when `g` is present, but A when `m` is unary, although `g` does not add anything about U.

I am also confused if this is an issue in ECJ or javac as ECJ accepts the code and javac doesn't. Only one of them can be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any reference issue, but the current Java 9 early access build compiles the code without an error. From this I would conclude that it is an issue in Java 8, not in ECJ.